# UpdateTextInput to return to initial values in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Can I use the function updateNumericInput() for returning my value to the initial one?

I made my first attempt and it works but I have to define the initial values as a global variable.

```
mean<-0
sd<-1
num<-100

library(shiny)
ui<-shiny::fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Normal Histogram"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "n",label = "number of samples",min = 0,max = 1000,value=num),
      numericInput(inputId="m", label="Mean",value=mean),
      numericInput(inputId="sd",label="Standard Deviation",value=sd),
      actionButton(inputId = "reset", label="reset")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "hist"))
  )
)

server<-function(input,output,session){
  output$hist<-shiny::renderPlot(
    hist(rnorm(input$n,mean=input$m,sd=input$sd),main="Histogram of a Custom Normal",xlab="")
  )
  observeEvent(input$reset,{updateNumericInput(session,"m",value = mean);updateNumericInput(session,"sd",value = sd);updateSliderInput(session,"n",value = num)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may save the constants as `reactiveValues` and use `renderUI` to load the UI components from the server side.

```
library(shiny)

ui<- shiny::fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Normal Histogram"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("n"),
      uiOutput("m"), 
      uiOutput("sd"), 
      actionButton(inputId = "reset", label="reset")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "hist"))
  )
)

server<-function(input,output,session){
  rv <- reactiveValues(mean = 0, sd = 1, num = 100)
  
  output$hist<-shiny::renderPlot({
    req(input$n, input$m, input$sd)
    hist(rnorm(input$n,mean=input$m,sd=input$sd),main="Histogram of a Custom Normal",xlab="")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    updateNumericInput(session,"m",value = rv$mean);
    updateNumericInput(session,"sd",value = rv$sd)
    updateSliderInput(session,"n",value = rv$num)
  })
  
  output$n <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(inputId = "n",label = "number of samples",min = 0,max = 1000,value=rv$num)
  })
  
  output$m <- renderUI({
    numericInput(inputId="m", label="Mean",value=rv$mean)
  })
  
  output$sd <- renderUI({
    numericInput(inputId="sd",label="Standard Deviation",value=rv$sd)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```